# What is the syntax for performing a parameterised delete using joins in SSIS 2008?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-delete

I'm trying to use an OLE DB Command to perform a delete using data from each row of my input file. The actual query works fine when running manually in sql server (given tableB.otherID is compared to an int), but I'm having issues parameterising it.

```
delete tableA from tableA
where tableA.ID = ?
```

The above query runs, and allows me to assign one of my input columns to tableA.ID. This is what I would expect.

Trying

```
delete tableA from tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.ID = tableA.ID
where tableB.OtherID = ?
```

Throws up an error however ("The multi-part identifier tableB.OtherID could not be bound"). Hardcoding a value in place of the '?' stops this error from appearing.

It seems like this would be the correct syntax, is there anything wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug/limitation with SSIS, I've found myself unable to perform similar parameterised update statements using a join.

Solution I ended up using was creating a temporary stored procedure with the delete statement I wanted, and passing the parameter to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the TSQL syntax you want is:

```
DELETE FROM tableA 
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.ID = tableA.ID 
WHERE tableB.OtherID = ?
```

Comment: This is the correct TSql, and should work in any normal case. The above still throws the same error when used within SSIS though, it seems perhaps to be a quirk of the technology?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tableA 
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.ID = tableA.ID 
WHERE tableB.OtherID = @OrderId
```

Where @OrderID should be your variable in SSIS.

Comment: This is going to be executed once per row in my input dataset, with the value being compared against changing each time. I believe you are thinking of the Execute SQL task within Control flow, where your solution would work, instead of OLE DB Command within Data flow.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many rows you need to delete using an Execute Sql task becomes slow quite quickly.

If that happens the solution that worked for me is putting the keys of the rows that need to be deleteed into a staging table, then when they're all in there issue one statement that deletes all those rows in a single statement and purges the staging table. Much quicker that way, added beneift is that you don;t have to use the quirky ? syntax. I never liked that, much too easy to mix stuff up when the sql becomes a little more complicated.

Regards Gert-Jan